# how to write google cloud function to store user input from dialogflow to datastore?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written a cloud function to store user input from dialogflow, it runs but finishes with crash.The function is deployed successfully, but data is not directly storing to datastore.

Here's my function:

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');
const Datastore = require['@google-cloud/datastore'];


const kind = 'package';




exports.package = (req,res) => {

 let email = req.body.result.contexts[0].parameters['email.original'];
 let phone = req.body.result.contexts[0].parameters['phone-number.original'];
 let date = req.body.result.contexts[0].parameters['date.original'];
 let number = req.body.result.contexts[0].parameters['number.original'];
 let city = req.body.result.contexts[0].parameters['geo-city.original'];


        console.log('email is '+email);
        console.log('phone is '+phone);
        console.log('date is '+date);
        console.log('city is '+city);
        console.log('number is '+number);

    function randomIntInc(low,high){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(high - low + 1)+low);
    }

    let packagenum = randomIntInc(1111,9999);

    const task = {

        data: {
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            date: date,
            city: city,
            number: number,

        }
    };
console.log('package is '+task);

Datastore.save(task)
.then(() =>{
    console.log(`saved ${task.key}: ${task.data.description}`);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    res.send(JSON.stringify({'speech': "your package number/id is"+packagenum}))
});

.catch{(err)=>{
 console.error('ERROR',err);
 res.setheader{'Content-type','application/json'};
```

}
 }

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Currently there are no errors, the execution is finishing with crash and the data from dialogflow is not storing to the datastore.  I am following this video :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5r4AAIfe4Rw&t=531s      in this it is missing 10 lines(29-39).I am new to cloud functions and javascript, so please help me with this.

Comment: crash? What crash?

Comment: Did you ever find the bug?